# jquery responsive image crossfade transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-fade

Does anyone knows how to transform this jQuery effect, instead of having fixed sized images, I need to set the size in percentage (width:100%; height:auto) so they can be responsive. Any ideas?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    $('img.fade').each(function (){
        var $$ = $(this);

        var target = $$.css('background-image').replace(/^url|[\(\)'"]/g, '');

        $$.wrap('<span style="position: relative;"></span>')
            .parent() // span elements
            .prepend('<img>')
            .find('img:first')
            .attr('src', target);

        $$.css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'left' : 0,
            'top' : this.offsetTop 
            });

        $$.hover(function () {
            $$.stop().animate({
                opacity: 0.2
            }, 250);
        }, function () {
            $$.stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 350);
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Let us see some HTML.

Comment: cant edit my question the only function available is share, and i can only answer it in 8 hours...is it because im new to this site and dont have enough reputation?

Comment: If you can't edit, then start up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the HTML and JS and post a link in the comments.

Comment: sorry about all this im a newbie :), well here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zATj6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean that the background image isn't scaling.

You could use the css command "background-size" to solve this problem..

Values that could help you are "cover" or "contain":
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

```
var target = $$.css('background-image').replace(/^url|[\(\)'"]/g, '').css({ 'background-size': 'cover' });
```

If this is not working, you could read out the actual absolute width of your image an set it as background-size. But then you need an resize-event for when you're scaling the browser window..

I would recommend to use two pictures and show/hide the pictures instead of using a background-image for the hover.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, with CSS style (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zATj6/1/ ) i can make the primary image appear correctly, but the background image appears in full size, when i put the values you recommended it scaled to the primary image size, but the animation stopped working. Does the show/hide two pictures method makes a crossfader effect?

Comment: Yes this is possible with the jQuey-Effects "fadeIn()" and "fadeOut" :)

If you put your images inside a box, you can use the hover function to fade the hover-pic in and out:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzCx3/

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very close to what i need. I'm going to test it out on my project to see if it works. Ill let you know the results. Cheers

Comment: It works :), but to achieve the crossover effect i wanted, i just had to mess with the opacity (in photoshop since the jQuery function fadeIn doesn't let me change the opacity, at least i couldn't do it) of the hidden image, so when it fades in i can still see a bit of the original image. Again, thank you very much for your help.